# What's the best software to draw algorithms in Ubuntu

Tags: paint

What is the best tool for **drawing algorithm models**? I want to use it for my thesis.

I want tools for drawing images like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIfca.jpg).

I use Ubuntu Version 17.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a vector drawing application such as [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/). It is very versatile and should be suitable for any of your diagram drawing needs. [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org), is also very good but is a raster editor and so is more suited to photo editing than diagrams.

Additionally, there are several specialised tools for drawing specific kinds of diagrams. For example, [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) is commonly used for drawing node graphs. [Mermaid](https://mermaidjs.github.io) is a node module for drawing flow diagrams which also has a [command line interface](https://github.com/mermaidjs/mermaid.cli). Also, if you are writing your thesis in LaTeX then you could look at the [Tikz](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/TikZ_package) and [algorithms](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms) package.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I used the Tikz package in LaTex to drow the diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

There are several diagramming tools. Some are easier than others.

If you are you asking which are easier to get started with or are more complete, the more established programs might have more "stencils" created for it but might be a bit harder to start with.

Dia is one of the best known ones but it takes a bit to get started. I would start with something like LibreOffice Draw and it might be all you need.
[Here are some alternatives to Dia](https://alternativeto.net/software/dia/?platform=linux)

Comment: I edited your answer to make it more an answer than a question.